# DIFFERENT webpages Same URL

Tags: excel, database, maatwebsite-excel

I hope this finds you in good shape.
I'm attempting to scrape data for my colleagues, and I've noticed that various websites can share the same URL. This has given me problems because I won't be able to scrape the data I require. Is there a solution to this.
Colgate's website in question is depicted below. The corporate vice-president tab and the leadership tab share the same URL. Can someone tell me how to scrape their names and roles or tell me how to find their individual URLs?
https://www.colgatepalmolive.com/en-us/who-we-are/our-leadership-team

Answer (score 0):

You’re going to need more complex logic than just screen-scraping.  The nature of object-oriented web scripting means that these links don’t work the way you think they do.

If you imagine a web page as static HTML, then each link is a discrete URL that the web server receives, interprets, and displays.

But most web pages aren’t static HTML anymore.  When you click on the picture for Joe Smith you are not sending a message to the web server to retrieve and send another static HTML page that contains Joe’s bio.  Rather your click is sending a message to the “Joe Smith Object” and telling it “please display the bio portion of your object.”  The message never says “open the Joe Smith” bio, it simply says “open *your* bio.  How does it know which one to open?  The “display your bio” message only gets sent to whichever object the user clicked on.  If Joe’s,object gets the message, the request Is for Joe’s bio.  If Jane’s object received the message, the request is for Jane’s bio.